# API : Ticker info

Tags: coinbase-api

The **[Coinbase Exchange API: ticker](https://docs.exchange.coinbase.com/?python#get-product-ticker)** `GET /products/<product-id>/ticker` only provides the last close. In order to place a market order, I need the best ask and bid (based on the side) price. Almost all exchanges provide this with their ticker API, so I am little surprised coinbase doesn't.

What am I missing? Is there any way I can get that information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Order Book endpoint: `GET /products/<product-id>/book` to get that information. Further details are available [here](https://docs.exchange.coinbase.com/#get-product-order-book).

Answer (score 0):

Doing it with rest template, java. The end point to hit is:

```
$ while true ; do  curl  http://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/ticker ;  echo   ;  done
```

Make sure, you use https. http will return nothing

```
 while true ; do  curl  http://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/ticker ;  echo   ;  done
```